# Estimate confusion matrix for each split in LeaveoneOut sklearn

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

It is possible to estimate the confusion matrix for each split in `LOOCV`?. I am pretty navy in sklearn and I was reading the documentation about `LeaveOneOut` in `sklearn.model_selection` and I have a good how idea what it means `LOOC` and the data is splitted. But I was wondering if there is a way to represent the confusion matrix in each split carried out by `LOOC` method.
What I was trying was something related to `Kfold` as it is represented in documentation but what I am getting is pretty strange to me. This is what I was testing:

```
iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
######################### LOOCV ##############################
clf = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut
loo = LeaveOneOut()
print(loo.get_n_splits(X))
#150 scores (all either 1 or 0 why?)
print(cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=loo, n_jobs=-1))
y_pred = cross_val_predict(clf,X,y,cv=loo)
#I am not sure about this line. As far as I am concerned should be the confusion matrix with LOOCV but without the data splitted?
print('Confusion matrix after LOOCV without splitting the data: \n{}'.format(confusion_matrix(y,y_pred))
for train, test in loo.split(X):
    y_pred_prob = clf.fit(X[train], y[train]).predict_proba(X[test])
    y_pred_class = clf.predict(X[test])
    #confusion matrix for each split carried out by LOOCV
    conf_mat = metrics.confusion_matrix(y[test], y_pred_class)
    print('Confusion matrix: \n{}'.format(conf_mat))
```

What I am getting by doing this are almost 150 confusion matrix like this `[[1]]`. Shouldn't be 3x3 matrixes?
Any help or advice would be welcomed, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by supplying the classes of your data by using the `labels` param in confusion matrix.

Since you are using LeaveOneOut, so each time only a single sample is used for testing and so only a single prediction is present. It makes no sense to use the confusion matrix in that case. But still if you want you can use the following code:

```
for train, test in loo.split(X):
    y_pred_prob = clf.fit(X[train], y[train]).predict_proba(X[test])
    y_pred_class = clf.predict(X[test])
    #confusion matrix for each split carried out by LOOCV
    conf_mat = confusion_matrix(y[test], y_pred_class, labels=[0,1,2])
    print('Confusion matrix: \n{}'.format(conf_mat))
```

labels=[0,1,2] denote the classes present in the data.